# Add multiple contacts (emails) to an UI component

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am building an iPhone app, and it will have a Settings page which contains a UI component holding a bunch of preset email addresses, from your Address Book. I am thinking to build it to be like this:

[image: Picture of three token bubbles and an "Add" button]

this screenshot is essentially from the Email App, where you can add/remove multiple recipients. Does anyone know if it's a component provided by Apple?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **three20 lib**. It's cool.

https://github.com/facebook/three20

[image]

Comment: +1 because this _is_ a solution, but man I hate using the three20 framework.

Answer (score 1):

Guess I'll answer my own question here - the closest thing i can find is this :

https://github.com/jasarien/JSTokenField

found via http://www.cocoacontrols.com/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are after:

```
NSArray *recipients = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"test@example.com", nil];
[picker setToRecipients: recipients];
[recipients release];
```

Where `picker` is an MFMailComposeViewController.

You could potentially search their address book for your preset email addresses, or hardcode them into this array if they don't need to change. The user can always add/remove more from the mail controller anyway.

Comment: Thanks Luke. I need this UI component to be standalone - then i will save the preset emails to a plist NSArray for later use.

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is a component , well , you can use the

```
ABAddressBook Framework 
ABAddressBookUI Framework
```

but you must be careful  because you can damage the address book.

you can start by retrieving the current addressbook by

```
ABAddressBook addressbook = ABAddressBookCreate();
```

and then you can create a new person by

```
 ABRecordRef person = ABPersonCreate();
```

and add properties

```
ABPersonSetValue(person,kABPersonFirstName,@"yourname",nil);
```

then add the person to the addressbook

```
ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressbook,person,nil);
```

and don't forget to save

```
ABAddressBookSave(addressbook,nil);
```

see that are many properties in the class reference :

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/Reference/AddressBook/Classes/ABAddressBook_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Hope this was helpful!

Comment: This has nothing to do with the UI control the OP was asking about.